# Can I fetch the JMS queue details without using Administration Console?

Tags: java, jms

I want to fetch all the details of the JMS like what all queues are there and how many messages are present. Can I fetch all these details from backend? If there is any file which stores all these details where I can look. Any help, please.

Comment: Did my answer address your comment? If so please mark it as correct to help other users who have this same question in the future. If not please elaborate as to what is lacking. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The JMS specification doesn't define how to retrieve the kind of information you're looking for. Therefore, the solution to your problem will be based on what kind of JMS server you're using and whether or not it provides access to the data you need.

For example, [ActiveMQ Artemis](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/) provides programmatic access to a wealth of metrics and administrative data through HTTP, JMX, and even specially constructed JMS messages. You can read more about this in [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/management.html).